# Cumilitive log in SAS EG

Tags: sas

Long story short - Familiar with BASE 9, now using EG (7.1) due to a new role with another company. The transition is painful, but there is one thing that bothers me the most and that is the log.

As I am sure most know, it will rewrite/refresh for every piece of code you execute.

Surely there must be an option to maintain a "running log" within the SAS code you are running/building (not necessarily for the whole project, but just for the program node within the project).

Can this be done?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Searched for some reference, but none citing the subject specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - from SAS's [support pages](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/138-2013.pdf):

> You’ll notice that a separate log node is generated for each code node. By turning on **Project Logging**, you can
>   easily tell Enterprise Guide that you’d like a single SAS log to be generated for all of the tasks and code nodes in your
>   Project. This single Project Log will be created in addition to the individual logs created for each task or code node.
>
> Helpful Hint: If Project Logging is turned on, the log represents a running log of the entire project. **To
>   turn on the Project Logging, select Project Log in the Context Menu of the Process Flow, and then select
>   Turn On.**

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Assuming you cant do this through the normal log, only the project log? Either way, Ill take it! Thank you much.